# What is wrong in the code? I am getting this Warning. (PHP Warning: Illegal string offset 'refferal')

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I need your help to find that what is wrong in the code. I am getting a warning like (PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'refferal')

Please help me to fix it.
Thank you!

```
function check_if_referrer_has_manual_link( $buyer_id ) {
    $linkarray = get_option( 'rewards_dynamic_rule_manual' ) ;
    if ( ! srp_check_is_array( $linkarray ) )
        return false ;

    foreach ( $linkarray as $key => $eachreferer ) {
        if ( $eachreferer[ "refferal" ] == $buyer_id )
            return $eachreferer[ 'referer' ] ;
    }
    return false ;
}
```

Comment: maybe your array doesn't have 'referer' key or index in it.

Comment: Sounds like `$eachreferer` is a string, but you are accessing it as an array,.

Comment: Regarding the flagged duplicate "Illegal string offset Warning PHP", see the second answer and not the accepted one.

Comment: @Qirel, print_r($eachreferer); return array

Comment: @Ibnelaiq, 'referer' key is in array

Comment: Not according to the message you posted here, then its a string.